# Make TS warn me when I pass method reference

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

When I pass a function reference as a parameter to another function and then call it somewhere, it loses "this". To prevent it I have to turn the method to arrow function. Here is an illustration of what I mean:

```
class Meeseeks{
  private line="I'm mister Meeseeks";
  lookAtMe(){ console.log(this.line+', look at me!'); }
}
// somewhere else:
let mr = new Meeseeks();
mr.lookAtMe();/// ok, prints fine
function callIt(fn:Function){ fn(); }
callIt(mr.lookAtMe);/// this one throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'line' of undefined"
```

So the only way to fix it is to turn "lookAtMe" into an arrow function:

```
  lookAtMe = () =>  console.log(this.line+', look at me!');
```

My question is: could TypeScript warn me when I use a function reference? Because I hate runtime errors when they can be caught on compilation time, this is why I use TypeScript in a first place (I am very fond of strictly typed languages). And now, to prevent it, I make *all* methods arrow functions, and it's not good for inheritance.

Any tsconfig entry or tslint entry you are aware of?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but this can be prevented by a few `bind`s in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to directly warn against this.

There was a [suggestion for ESLint to implement it](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/861) but it was not implemented.

What you *could* do is use the [only-arrow-function TSLint rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/only-arrow-functions/) to prevent the behaviour from occuring in the first place.

Comment: @Downvoter: why the downvote? This is a correct and valid answer to the question, which wants to implement a build process step to prevent function references.

Comment: Your assumption that the user is not interested in any approach which will report such errors without any changes whatsoever to the source code, and that any such approach--which does in fact exist--by definition not only fails to answer his question but does not even deserve to be mentioned, seems overly stringent, and not supported by anything other than the OP's casual mention of eslint or tsconfig flags. Your link to the ESLint issue is about something different altogether.